# How to import data with dates as index from excel with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am importing the data with this command

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Me/Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Prices')
```

and this is the result:

[image: 1]

The date is a common column and I want it like this:

[image: 2]

Comment: Hi! Please don’t post images of the data as we can’t test them. Instead, post a sample of the DataFrame and expected output directly inside a code block. This allows us to easily reproduce your problem and help you. Take the time to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revise your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.Adding `parse_dates=True`, `index_col=0` to the import command like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Me/Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Prices', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
```

The output is this:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to set Date as an index, if I get it right:

```
df.set_index('Date')
```

Comment: This answer should go as a comment, really, but I don't have yet enough reputation... Maybe you want to edit the question so to make clear you are asking for an index, if this is what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to import them, because when I was trying to calculate the monthly returns it does not work. So I use this new code and the date were perfect.

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Me/Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Prices')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.drop(['Date'], axis = 'columns', inplace=True)
df.head()
```

and this is the result:

[image: 1]